# How will it be fixed so that it can catch mentioned URL formats?

Tags: java, python, c++, c, regex

URL detector in a string is what I am worked on. In the code, as you can see, pattern tries to find URL in the string. However, it cannot detect;

- www.website.com
- www.website.edu
- www.website.gov
- ww2.sample.co.uk
- ftp ...

My pattern

```
Pattern.compile("\\(*https?://[-\\w+&@#/½=~()|?!:,.;]*[-\\w+&@#/%=~()|]");
```

How will it be fixed so that it can catch mentioned website formats?

For simplicity, **expected input** and **output** is;

www.website.com  -----> www.website.com

For *real situation*, I will use it in

109*20210adlkwaokwww.website.com121^'^)'^209  -----> www.website.com

I am open to hear answer on both  case.

Comment: If you go around making abusive comments about other users you are going to get yourself suspended. Stop it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I can notice, you expect the pattern to catch  the website with or without http/https - this is not included in your expression.

What is more, I am not sure what the purpose of \(* is - ((((((https://some.url.com will also be caught.

Is https://½½½½½½½½½½½½ a valid url? It will be accepted. What about http://= (sorry for ugly escaping the . with ) ?

https://test.com. (with a dot at the end) IS a valid URL and will not.

Try Something like this:

```
(https?://)?\\w+[\\w-.]*
```

Note that not all acceptable characters are included because I am plain lazy, refer to RFC 3986 for those. Also see http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/url-spec.txt

Answer (score 0):

```
\b(((?#protocol)https?|ftp)://)?((?#domain)[-A-Z0-9.]+)((?#file)/[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?((?#parameters)\?[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?
```

`'?#'` comment;